# How to create tables automatically in Redshift through AWS Glue based on RDS data source

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, aws-glue, aws-glue-data-catalog

I have dozens of tables in my data source (RDS) and I am ingesting all of this data into Redshift through AWS Glue. I am currently manually creating tables in Redshift (through SQL) and then proceeding with the Crawler and AWS Glue to fill in the Redshift tables with the data flowing from RDS.

Is there a way I can create these target tables within Redshift automatically (based on the tables I have in RDS, as these will just be an exact same copy initially) and not manually create each one of them with SQL in the Redshift Query Editor section?

Thanks in advance,